# Trying to use a text file instead of a string variable

Tags: python

i have done research and have been unable to find the solution to my problem. Basically i want my code to do the exact same thing as it is doing now, but i want to be able to replace my sentence variable with a text file. Here is my current code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sentence= ("I met a traveller from an antique land, Who said Two vast and                 trunkless legs of stone. Stand in the desert. . . . Near them, on the sand,  Half sunk a shattered visage lies, whose frown, And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command, Tell that its sculptor well those passions read Which yet survive, stamped on these lifeless things, The hand that mocked them, and the heart that fed; And on the pedestal, these words appear: My name is Ozymandias, King of Kings; Look on my Works, ye Mighty, and despair! Nothing beside remains. Round the decay Of that colossal Wreck, boundless and bare The lone and level sands stretch far away.").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')
lst = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))
numberLst = []
for i in words:
    numberLst.append(lst.index(i)+1)

words_str = ':'.join(words)
numberLst_str = ':'.join(str(e) for e in numberLst)

file = open("words.txt","w")
file.write(words_str)
file.close()

file=open("numberlst.txt","w")
file.write(numberLst_str)
file.close()

joinlst = " ".join(lst[i-1] for i in numberLst)

file=open("joinlst.txt","w")
file.write(joinlst)
file.close()

choice = input ("do you want to uncompress or compress the text file (type   compress or uncompress)")
if choice == "compress":
    print (numberLst)
else:
    if choice == "uncompress":
        print (joinlst)

print("your choice was",choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the entire contents of the file at `filename` into the variable `sentence`. Note that `sentence` will also include any newline characters (or other weird encoding junk), which you may need to filter out with `split(...)` and/or `trim(...)` calls.

```
sentence = ""
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    sentence = f.read()
```

Comment: cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8cheers m8

Comment: @alibongo Glad I could help! Please up-vote the post and select it as the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("some_text_file.txt", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        #do your thing
```

Put that at the top and use line to replace sentence from your code.